# How to increase the overall thickness of a banner in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm making a flutter app where there's a gridview of cards that shows details of different items in a list. In the top right corner of the card I added a banner using the banner widget that shows the current status of the item.
[image: What the banner currently looks like]

This is what the banner looks like. But I want to move the banner a bit more to the corner as well as make it more wider.

```
Card(
  elevation: 1.0,
  child: ClipRect(
    child: Banner(
      textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      message: 'OPEN'
      location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
      color: const Color(0xFF0db3ae),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('......')
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is the basic structure of the code I used to make the cards and to make sure the banner wraps around the card. But i can't find a way to increase it's width or move it a bit more to the corner.

Comment: The default banner widget does not have a way to customize the thickness or how far it is from the corner. But you can always define your own custom banner class that behaves differently. You can see how the default banner is defined [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fb57da5f94/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/banner.dart). You could make a `CustomBanner` and `CustomBannerPainter` that behaved nearly the same way, but used different values for `_kOffset` (distance from corner) and `_kHeight` (thickness of banner).

Answer (score 0):

Use Ribbon instead.

```
//
import 'package:ribbon/ribbon.dart';

Ribbon(
nearLength: nearLength,
farLength: farLength,
title: 'New!',
titleStyle: TextStyle(
color: Colors.greenAccent,
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
color: Colors.redAccent,
location: location,
child: )
```

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/ribbon_widget